# Dynamically register MEF exports with runtime-defined contracts

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I am trying to dynamically (using reflection) add types to a MEF catalog and also define the export contract at runtime. The issue is MEF will simply use the fully qualified name of the type as the contract, and I need to specify the export contract as a specific interface type.

Here is the code I use to get the types I need to add to the MEF catalog:

```
private void RegisterSupportedRepositories(Func<ObjectContext> contextProvider)
    {
        var context = contextProvider();
        var properties = context.GetType().GetProperties();
        var entitySets = properties.Where(property => property.PropertyType.Name == typeof(ObjectSet<>).Name);

        foreach (var entitySet in entitySets)
        {
            var entityType = entitySet.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var repositoryType = typeof(EFRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
            ComponentServices.RegisterComponent(repositoryType);                
        }
    }
```

> ComponentServices.RegisterComponent is defined below, it gets an AggregateCatalog (from where isn't relevant) and then adds TypeCatalogs to the aggregate catalog:

```
public static void RegisterComponent(Type componentType)
    {
        var catalog = RetrieveCatalog();

        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new TypeCatalog(componentType));
    }
```

I need to be able to specify the contract of the added types as an interface, this would normally be done with Export attributes that look like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IRepository<Customer>))]
```

The question is how do I add this export contract dynamically, so that the export is equivalent to what's shown above and not the default "EFRepository" contract that MEF infers from the type itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the CodePlex preview version of MEF, I'd recommend using the new RegistrationBuilder to do this.  Here's a blog post describing it: [MEF's Convention Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/archive/2011/03/08/mef-s-convention-model.aspx)

If you can't use the preview version, you can use the methods in [ReflectionModelServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.reflectionmodel.reflectionmodelservices.aspx) to create your own part definitions, and create a catalog implementation that uses them.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for pointing me down the right path, I've built my own type catalog that uses both ReflectionModelServices and AttributedModelServices; now I'm able to dynamically add non-attributed types to MEF.